# Hiding seconds of input time in PhoneGap + Android 4.4

Tags: android, html, cordova

The HTML5 time input has an attribute step. Setting this to 60 it is supposed to hide away the seconds and only showing hours:minutes. Testing following on Android 4.4 (http://jsfiddle.net/9ut9a/)

```
<input type="time" step="60">
```

works in both native web browser as well as in Android Chrome, but when using this in my PhoneGap Android application it always show seconds. I have even tried setting maxLength to 5. Is there any way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: have u got this issue cleared? Because i am facing this issue currently